# Blackberry: Speeding up Simulator start

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

Running any Blackberry Simulator for the JDE takes forever to launch. Any ideas on speeding it up? I see that it looks through a bunch of generic files while booting up, can I strip it down?  All I want to do is test my app, which only relies on e-mail, maps and the contact book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a JRE/JDE and simulator both 5.0 or higher, you can use the [Code Hot Swap](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/04/new-code-hot-swap-feature/) feature to update the app in a running simulator without having to restart it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will investigate. But my target OS is 4.6 and up :(

Comment: Well you can still use the hot-swap method for the "back-and-forth" type of development (i.e. tweaking the UI) then switch back to older JRE/JDK and simulator later to make sure it works fine on those devices.

Comment: Any suggestions for 4.6 simulators?

Comment: Not really, just try a couple and pick the one that loads up the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that can be done, but only if you don't need the functionality.

Both of these are from the Edit -> Preferences -> Simulator Tab (this assumes you are using the JDE)

1) If you don't need connectivity for your app, on the Simulator -> Network tab, make sure "Disable Registration" and "Start with radio off" are checked.

2) If you don't need MMC support, on the Simulator -> Memory tab, make sure "Do not support Multimedia Card Simulation" is checked.

I'm not sure how much this will help, but it should make it a bit faster.